# Invoke a method of templated derived class method from non-template base class pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to implement a Property system in my project similar to Property system in Qt. We just started with some ideas and are in **prototyping** stage.
Basically, what I understood from Qt is, client should be able to pass the get function, set function and property type through some macro in the .h file. So I tried to mimic the same.

Following is my sample code:

Abstract getter class. This type of getter class is a member in Property Class

```
class AbstractFunc
{
public:
  template < typename R > 
  R Invoke ()
  {
    return (this)->Invoke ();
  }
};
```

Get Function template: Return values can be T , T&, const T& , T* etc..

```
template < typename R, class T > class GetterFunction : public AbstractFunc
{
  typedef R (T::*GetterFunc) ();

public:
  GetterFunction (T * obj, GetterFunc func):m_Obj (obj), m_Func (func)
  {
  }

  R Invoke ()
  {
    return m_Obj->*(m_Func) ();
  }

public:
  T * m_Obj;
  GetterFunc m_Func;
};
```

Property Class:

```
class Property
{
public:
  Property (string name, AbstractFunc* getter):m_name (name), m_getter (getter)
  {

  }

  template < typename R > R GetValue ()
  {
    return m_getter->Invoke < R > ();
  }

private:
  string m_name;
  AbstractFunc* m_getter;
};
```

Some Window Class:

```
class Window
{
public:

};
```

Example window class

```
class CheckBox :public Window
{
public:
  int GetChecked ()
  {
    return m_checked;
  }
  void SetChecked (int nChecked)
  {
    m_checked = nChecked;
  }

  void AddProperty (string name)
  {
    m_prop = new Property (name, new GetterFunction< int, Checked >(this, &Checked::GetChecked));
  }

  int m_checked;
  Property *m_prop;
};
```

main function:

```
int main ()
{

  CheckBox cc;
  cc.AddProperty ("Hello");

  cout<<"value:"<< cc.m_prop->GetValue<int>();

  return 0;
}
```

PROBLEM:
Getter function is remembered as AbstractFunc in Property Class. I want to call 'Invoke' on AbstractFunc* instance and it should invoke the member function and **return correct return type**. The above code throws error at AbstractFunc::Invoke.

[see live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94912a1302e6cc86)

Comment: `return (this)->Invoke ();` This makes no sense. The function just calls itself. Perhaps you want to make this function pure virtual instead. No wait you cannot, it's a template. It looks like you cannot have such function at all. "it should invoke the member function and return correct return type" What is the correct type?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The desired interface looks like much like `std::any` and `std::any_cast`, where you pass the type you expect at the point you get a value from it. If you're wrong about the type, you fail to get a value. Certainly possible to implement. OP is just going about it completely the wrong way.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, I cannot make it virtual function.return (this)->Invoke (); Actually this can invoke the derived class function if I cast to derived class. OK but that is blunder. Regarding "it should invoke the member function and return correct return type", Invoke function should return correct type for ex: for function int GetChecked(), Invoke() should return int; int& GetChecked(), Invoke() should return int&.

Comment: @HTNW yes it is possible to implement of course. You could give every single variable the type of `std::any` and do `any_cast` before every use. But why would you want it?

Comment: "Actually this can invoke the derived class function if I cast to derived class" OK go ahead and cast it, what's the problem? Do you know what the derived class is right there?

Comment: No. the derived class type is unknown and here the type is GetterFunction< int, Checked >. I can't cast to it.

Comment: @HTNW: could you explain more about your suggestion. Or point me to a reference.thank you in advance

Comment: You can introduce an intermediate class `template <class T> SpecificAbstractFunc : public AbstractFunc` so that you know what the derived class is: it's `SpecificAbstractFunc<R>`. But now why do you need `AbstractFunc` in the first place? Just use `SpecificAbstractFunc<int>` or whatever.

Comment: In Property class I need to store GetterFunction< int, Checked >* in a abstract way. There will be multiple such properties in a registry which is not shown in example. Each property will have different GetterFunction. Ex: For enable property the getter isGetterFunction<int&, Enable>. For color property GetterFunction<Color, GetColor>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AbstractFunc` isn't abstract at all: its `Invoke` isn't virtual. So even though `GetterFunction` also has a method named `Invoke`, that method doesn't actually override `AbstractFunc::Invoke`; it just hides it. When you try to call `Invoke` through the `AbstractFunc*`, it calls `AbstractFunc::Invoke`, which goes into infinite recursion and thus produces UB.

I would follow @n.m.'s suggestion to make a class hierarchy like so:

```
class AbstractFunc {
  // lock down construction
  AbstractFunc() = default;
public:
  template<typename R>
  R Invoke();
  template<typename R>
  bool HasType() const noexcept;
  virtual ~AbstractFunc() = default; // need to have SOME virtual method so that we have runtime type info; also a virtual destructor is required anyway

  template<typename R>
  friend class TypedFunc;
};
template<typename R>
struct TypedFunc : AbstractFunc { // the ONLY instances of AbstractFunc are also instances of specializations of TypedFunc
  virtual R InvokeTyped() = 0;
};
// one kind of TypedFunc applies a getter on an object
template<typename R, typename T>
struct GetterFunc : TypedFunc<R> {
  // you never see a GetterFunc in the interface anyway... don't see a need to hide these
  T *obj; // have you considered std::shared_ptr?
  R (T::*getter)();
  GetterFunc(T *obj, R (T::*getter)()) : obj(obj), getter(getter) { }
  R InvokeTyped() override { return (obj->*getter)(); }
};
template<typename R, typename T>
std::unique_ptr<GetterFunc<R, T>> MakeGetterFunc(T *obj, R (T::*getter)()) {
  return std::make_unique<GetterFunc<R, T>>(obj, getter);
}
// another kind applies a functor, etc.
template<typename R, typename F>
struct FunctorFunc : TypedFunc<R> {
  F func;
  template<typename... G>
  FunctorFunc(G&&... args) : func(std::forward<G>(args)...) { }
  R InvokeTyped() override { return func(); }
};
```

This is already usable: if you have an `AbstractFunc*` or an `AbstractFunc&`, you can `dynamic_cast` it down to a `TypedFunc` of the expected type (e.g. `TypedFunc<int>`). If that succeeds (you get a nonnull pointer or there is no `std::bad_cast` exception), then you just call `InvokeTyped` without having to know what kind of `GetterFunc`/`FunctorFunc`/whatever you are actually dealing with. The functions `Invoke` and `HasType` declared in `AbstractFunc` are just sugar to help do this.

```
template<typename R>
bool AbstractFunc::HasType() const noexcept {
  return dynamic_cast<TypedFunc<R> const*>(this);
}
template<typename R>
R AbstractFunc::Invoke() {
  return dynamic_cast<TypedFunc<R>&>(*this).InvokeTyped();
  // throws std::bad_cast if cast fails
}
```

Done.

```
class Property {
  std::string name;
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunc> getter;
public:
  Property(std::string name, std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunc> getter) : name(std::move(name)), getter(std::move(getter)) { }
  template<typename R>
  bool HasType() const noexcept { return getter->HasType<R>(); }
  template<typename R>
  R GetValue() const { return getter->Invoke<R>(); }
  std::string const &GetName() const noexcept { return name; }
};
struct Window {
  virtual ~Window() = default;
  // doesn't really make sense to add/remove these from outside...
  virtual std::vector<Property> GetProperties() = 0;
};
class CheckBox : public Window {
  int checked = 0;
public:
  int GetChecked() /*const*/ noexcept { return checked; }
  void SetChecked(int checked) noexcept { this->checked = checked; }
  std::vector<Property> GetProperties() override {
    std::vector<Property> ret;
    ret.emplace_back("Boxes Checked", MakeGetterFunc(this, &CheckBox::GetChecked));
    return ret;
  }
};

int main() {
  CheckBox cb;
  cb.SetChecked(5);
  for(auto const &prop : cb.GetProperties()) std::cout << prop.GetName() << ": " << prop.GetValue<int>() << "\n";
}
```

You could then add e.g. a `virtual std::type_info const& GetType() const` or similar to `AbstractFunc` if you want to be able to directly get at the type, etc.

Comment: Thank you @HTNW for showing the example. This works.
The only problem is dynamic_cast. But, I'll try something as you suggested to avoid it. Thank you for comments and for showing the direction to go. Will try to build on it.